# Cоздать файл строго по размерам изображения копируемого слоя

Tags: photoshop

В интернете существуют вот такие советы: 
*"На необходимом слое жмем Ctrl+A (выделить все) , потом Ctrl+C (копируем) , потом Ctrl+N (создаем новый файл) , потом Ctrl+V (вставляем) - при этих действиях файл создается строго по размерам изображения копируемого слоя (то есть если картинка, которую мы выделили, на слое была 100 на 150 px, то и новый файл будет 100 на 150 px)"*

У меня данный способ не работает. Почему? Такой функционал есть не во всех версиях программы? У меня Photoshop CC 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой способ есть во всех версиях программы, начиная с Photoshop 5 (даже не CS 5, а именно 5.0, до этого я пользовался другими программами, поэтому, может и раньше).
Может не работать в условиях:

1. в копируемом слое векторный объект
2. в копируемом слое используется специфическая маска
3. в наличии какой-то перехватчик буфера обмена